# DB/Eloquent clause to get all rows from today laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have a model which has a date. Since it's based a non-Gregorian calendar, I have to break the date into 3 columns dd, mm and yy to do operations on it.

I need to retrieve 3 rows that have the date of today or after.

I need to write a condition where

```
  yy >= today[year]
  mm >= today[month]
```

and for the result of this implement

```
  mm >= today[month]
  dd >= today[date]
```

How to write a clause to meet this condition?

I tried, this

```
$event = Model::select(['id','name'])
  ->where('yy','>=',today['year'])
  ->where('mm','>=',today['month'])
  ->where('dd','>=',today['date'])
  ->orderBy('yy','ASC')
  ->orderBy('mm','ASC')
  ->orderBy('dd','ASC')
  ->take(3)->get();
```

But this doesn't return rows whose dd are less than today[date] even if mm and yy are more than today[month] and today[year]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the where condition. Like;

```
$now = Carbon::now();

$result = Model::where('year', '>=', $now->getYear())->where('month', '>=', $now->getMonth())->where('day', '>=', $now->getMonth())->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't return rows whose dd are less than today[date] even if mm and yy are more than today[month] and today[year]. 

I have updated the question with what I had already tried.